# Display Results of SQL Query on WP site

Tags: php, mysql

I hope this is not redundant - but there always seems to be enough different that I cannot get things working.

I am building a function in my `functions.php` file - all other functions work fine.

```php
$query = $mydb->get_results("select * from table");
```

//This works just fine in mysql and I can do things like count(*) and get that to report back.

But for whatever reason I cannot get the table to return results that output to the wordpress page

```php
return "$query";
return "$query[0]";
return "$query["wk"]";
```

The only output I get to have displayed on any page is the word Array where I am expecting the output to be.

So something like this works perfectly -

```php
function VtVML_visitor(){
    $home = get_field('home');
    $visitor = get_field('visitor');
    $mydb = new wpdb('OMMITTED');
    
    $hWins = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where v = '$home' and h = '$visitor' and h_ml_win = 1");
    $hLoss = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where v = '$home' and h = '$visitor' and h_ml_loss = 1");
    $hTie = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where v = '$home' and h = '$visitor' and h_ml_tie = 1");
    $vWins = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where h = '$home' and v = '$visitor' and v_ml_win = 1");
    $vLoss = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where h = '$home' and v = '$visitor' and v_ml_loss = 1");
    $vTie = $mydb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM `table` where h = '$home' and v = '$visitor' and v_ml_tie = 1");

    $tWins = $vWins+$hWins;
    $tLoss = $vLoss+$hLoss;
    $tTie = $vTie+$hTie;
    
    return "$visitor vs $home overall:<br>$tWins - $tLoss - $tTie";
    
    $mydb -> close();
}

add_shortcode('VtVML','VtVML_visitor');
```

But if I repurpose this into a new shortcode and change the queries to pull specific fields:

```php
$schedule = $mydb->get_var("SELECT wk,v,h FROM `table` where h = '$home'");

return "$schedule";
```

I see the error described above. I am assuming I need to do a foreach or while command - but all attempts to use these have not yielded results.

Comment: the code in your question is vulnerable to injection and escaping attacks. None of the sql queries are ran through `$wpdb->prepare` and have dynamic values inserted. Likewise you're embedding variables directly into HTML output without any escaping. You've also put the `$mydb->close` after the return statement, so it will never be reached

Comment: Also, `return "$thing";` on its own should just be `return $thing`, you don't need to wrap it in quotes

Comment: @TomJNowell - thanks Tom. To be clear, the variables are being read in from the database and are not open for end users to submit - is it still best practice to obfuscate those?

I am actively writing to get an MVP up - this guidance is very helpful; thank you!

Comment: Yes, just because it _should_ be ok, doesn't mean it will be ok, the only time you don't use `prepare` is when the SQL query is static with no variables. Escaping takes all the uncertainty out of output by enforcing assumptions. e.g. if I do `echo esc_url( $foo )` I will ***always*** get a URL, even if `$foo` contains javascript or a ransom message. It might be a garbled URL, but it is guaranteed to be a URL

Answer (score 0):

> I see the error described above. I am assuming I need to do a foreach or while command - but all attempts to use these have not yielded results.

Yes, shortcodes return strings, not arrays/lists. You need to convert your array/list into a single string. However, `get_var` assumes a single result. If you want multiple results you will need to use a different method of WPDB that allows multiple results, such as `get_results`:

```php
<?php

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );
```

The code also needs to use `$wpdb->prepare` to insert variables into the SQL statement. E.g.:

```php
$wpdb->query(
   $wpdb->prepare(
      "
      INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
      ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
      VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
      ",
      10,
      $metakey,
      $metavalue
   )
);
```

Notice that the `$metakey` and `$metavalue` variables are not inside the string as that would be insecure. Instead they have placeholders `%s` that get replaced with sanitised versions that prevent them from breaking the query or inserting malicious values

[See the official docs for examples on using `get_results`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#select-generic-results)